# Long Lived access token Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I have a facebook page and i want the feeds of page.
I am using graph api to get the access token but i have no idea how to convert that short-lived access token to long-lived access token

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
 client_id=APP_ID& client_secret=APP_SECRET& grant_type=fb_exchange_token& fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

If above link is used to get the long live access token then from where i can get App_Secret
Help Me if i am going on wrong approach.

Comment: how to user the above url?

Comment: are you hitting by curl?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. First of all, learn the basic concepts and the different kinds of the access tokens from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/access-tokens-and-types/)
2. To get the extended **User** token (validity: 2months) use the code you have mentioned in the question.

   You can get the app secret from the [Apps](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) page.
3. To get a never expiring token for your **fan page**. Follow the simple steps:

   - Using the user token you obtained through step 2, get the list of pages/apps-

     ```
     $facebook->api("/USER_ID/accounts");
     ```
   - Get the never expiring access token for any page-

     ```
     $facebook->api("/PAGE_ID?fields=access_token");
     ```

(You can use [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to check the validity of the token.)

Comment: sahil- on the graph api explorer tool, i have put the "/PAGE_ID?fields=access_token"  but in response i am not getting anything

Comment: then i guess you haven't followed each step properly. Check out the access token you are using

Comment: sahil- i have created a facebook page ,and i got the page_id and on graph api explorer i have just pasted it  and run the query . This is waht i have done ,do let me know if i have done anything wrong

Comment: first run - `/me/accounts`. Then click on the id you are looking for. Then append `?fields=access_token` in the field. This will give you temp page token. Then replace the access token in above field with the extended token of user you obtained in step 2 , and run the same query- you will get the immortal page token. If still not works , start chat.

Comment: sahil - with /me/accounts i am not getting id of page i am just getting id of app ,how can we chat -new to stackoverflow

Comment: How could i help you then? :-/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22374/discussion-between-vg108-and-sahil)

Comment: @VG108 I've followed your steps and everything seems to work, but when the user logs out the token is invalidated. Is there a way to have a page access token that works even if the user is logged out? Am I doing something wrong or there's no way to that?

Answer (score 13):

To get a long-lived access token you need to follow those steps:

1. Create an Application
2. Create a Page (your account need to be "administrator" of the page)
3. Associate the application to the Page (the same way you do it when
   you want to add a Page Tab to a Page)
4. Get a short-lived access token with the permission "manage_pages"
   associated to your Application.
5. [https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=**APP_ID**&scope=manage_pages&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html](https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=__APP_ID__&scope=manage_pages&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html)
6. then
           [https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=**APP_ID**&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&client_secret=**APP_SECRET**&code=**CODE_FROM_PREVIOUS_REQUEST**](https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=__APP_ID__&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&client_secret=__APP_SECRET__&code=__CODE_FROM_PREVIOUS_REQUEST__)
7. Using the Graph API Explorer with the request /me/accounts you can
   see the access tokens for each Pages that you are administrator.
       The problem is that those access token are short-lived.
8. Convert your short-lived access token to a long-lived (extending
   access token):
9. https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=_APP_ID_&client_secret=_APP_SECRET_&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=_ACCESS_TOKEN_ON_STEP_4_

   You can now test your new access token with the Access Token Debugger.

Comment: Pragati - can u give detail step how to associate application to page

Comment: here __APP_ID__ is App ID and __APP_SECRET__ is App Secret of your application when you pass these value correctly and follow the above steps yours page will automatically associate with yours app.

Comment: Whats a mess, so If i want to get a feed of a page's lasts posts, I need an app token?